# preventDefault property in JS

Tags: javascript

The book that I am learning JS from has code like below :

```
function check(e) {
    if (!e){
    e = window.event; // for IE
    }
var target = e.target || e.srcTarget;
if (**e.preventDefault**){
e.preventDefault() ;
}
target.returnValue = false;
}
var el = document.getElementById("list");
el.addEventListener("click", check , false);
```

I understand that preventDefault is a method and not a property . I did not understand how they are doing a e.preventDefault in the if condition .I checked in chrome and did not find any property called preventDefault for e . There is a function under *proto* called preventDefault. Am I correct in assuming that all methods can be  changed to a property removing the () and  you can use it in your code to test if that method is available or not ?

Comment: Methods are still properties in JS. `e.preventDefault` is a function, and written without calling operator (`()`), the name of the function is a reference to that function. In a case the environment hasn't implemented `e.preventDefault` the expression will return `undefined`, otherwise it returns the referred function, which is interpreted as a truthy value in `if` condition. You've actually used the same mechanism – function refrence – when passing a function refrence (`check`) to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Cool ...I will test this out ..

Answer (score 0):

the double asterisks should not be there. 
if(e.preventDefault) will work because if checks if the passed argument isn't null. So when preventDefault function will be defined, the condition will be true.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for checking cross browser support. IE 8 or under won't support `preventDefault`, they use `returnValue`.

```
//check preventDefault function is exists in event handler 'e'
if (e.preventDefault) {
    // if browser support preventDefault, call preventDefault();
    e.preventDefault();
 }
```